# How to describe types for properties of class with flow?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    open: false,
  };
  this.input = null;
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

I have this error in `this.input = null`:

> Cannot assign `null` to `this.input` because property `input` is
>   missing in `MyComponent` [1]

Can't find answer on docs for flow.

Comment: What MyComponent? Can you add the complete class code? Are you writing a reactjs component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define types for instance properties at the top of the class definition -

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  input: string,
  handleChange: (event: Object) => mixed,

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
    this.input = null;
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  } 

}
```

Comment: Where did you find this approach? It dosn't help

Comment: Thank you! I have found that it's better to use `TimeoutID`
It looks like that

`class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
     inputTimer: TimeoutID
}`